# Django/ user registration by email activation - in class based view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, email-validation

I'm trying to register users but not making them active until they activate their accounts withe the email activation link but..

I get a **'UserBase' object has no attribute 'email_user'** error

and when changing it to 'email' instead of 'user_email' i get a
**'str' object is not callable** error

I get the activation link from the error page and it works when trying it on another tab (makes account active)

View:

```
class UserReigster(CreateView):
    model = UserBase
    form_class = Registration
    template_name = 'account/registration/registration.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()

        # Email Activation Setup
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        subject = 'Activate Your Account'
        message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user':user,
            'domain':current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)

        # Success registration message 
        messages.add_message(
            self.request,
            messages.SUCCESS,
            'Check Your Email For Account Activation Link'
        ) 

        return super().form_valid(form)

def account_activation(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
        
    except():
        pass

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')

    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

models:

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class UserBase(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)

    # Delivery Details
    country = CountryField()  
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    # User Status
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # Custom Manager
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Account'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

Comment: I would recommend you use `django-allauth`. If you want to know how it does it then take a look over the code, but it does what you want, and much more. https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: i forgot to make the email_user function in my models lol

Answer (score 1):

Using AbstractbaseUser in custom User you deleted the method email_user

You need to create it again in the custom user model:

```
def email_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
send_mail(
    '{}'.format(args[0]),
    '{}'.format(args[1]),
    '{}'.format(args[2]),
    [self.email],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```